# Stub ODATA service

Tags: web-services, odata, stub, mountebank

We will be building a Java/JS client that reads data from a server through ODATA.

What will be the easiest way to setup a stubbed ODATA server for our development and testing purposes. In the REST world I would have gone with [MounteBank](http://mbtest.org). Even this is doable using mountebank, only issue will be that i have to hard code all possible queries as a separate endpoint.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, figured out these two options.

1. https://github.com/TossShinHwa/node-odata

This supports v4.

2. https://github.com/htammen/n-odata-server

This supports v2.

The downside of both these libraries is that they don't support all the ODATA functions. But, decent enough to start with.